# ld can't find python-module-related functions while building on arch linux

Tags: python-2.7, cmake, archlinux

I am trying to build https://gitlab.com/dhyannataraj/goblin-camp/-/tree/cmake-build project (`cmake-build` branch) it uses `python2.7` and uses `cmake` as build system.

For debian-based distros all works ok. But for arch-linux all the code compiles well, but but when it comes to linking, a problem comes out

```
[ 35%] Linking CXX executable goblin-camp
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/goblin-camp.dir/Goblin_Camp/src/scripting/Engine.cpp.o: in function `Script::Init(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)':
Engine.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `inittime'
/usr/bin/ld: Engine.cpp:(.text+0x315): undefined reference to `init_functools'
/usr/bin/ld: Engine.cpp:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `initcStringIO'
/usr/bin/ld: Engine.cpp:(.text+0x31f): undefined reference to `initzlib'
```

All these `inittime`, `init_functools`, `initcStringIO` and `initzlib` they are part of python modules.

In other distros they are found out of box. But here it does not work for some reason.

So I have two questions:

1. What they actually misses? What package I should install to get it work? (I am stranger to arch linux, but I need it to work there too)
2. Have you any idea what should be added to `CMakeLists.txt` to detect this problem on configuring stage?

**Update:**
It seems to me that I found the cause of the problem.

In Debain-based distributives all binary python modules are gathered inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0` file. Meanwhile in Arch Linux, they are built separately in `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload` and cmake and linker does not find them.

The solution was to force cmake to import each module

```
add_library(python_zlib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET python_zlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so")

add_library(python_datetime SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET python_datetime PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so")

add_library(python__functools SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET python__functools PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so")

add_library(python_cStringIO SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET python_cStringIO PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so")
```

and them add it as an argument to `target_link_libraries`

```
target_link_libraries("goblin-camp"
  python_zlib
  python_datetime
  python__functools
  python_cStringIO
.....
```

Comment: It seems to me that I found the reason of the problem.

In Debain-based distributives all binary python modules are gathered inside ```/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0``` file. Meanwhile in Arch Linux, they are built separately in ```/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload``` and cmake and linker does not find them.

The solution was to force cmake to import each module

```
add_library(python_zlib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET python_zlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so")
```
and them add it as an argument to ```target_link_libraries```